# Show Custom Taxonomy as Headline for related posts

Tags: custom-field, terms

I have a post with related posts. I do the relation with the Advanced Custom Fields Plugin. 
It works that I can show all the related posts of the term, but in addition I want to show only the name of the term as headline. This doesn't works

```
//get Assistance
$post = $post_objects; // variable must be called $post (IMPORTANT)
setup_postdata($post);
if(!empty(is_object_in_term($post->ID, 'tshowcase-taxonomy',Assistence))) {
    //if ($loop->have_posts()) {

    echo '<h4><i>' . Assistence . '</i></h4>';

}else{
    echo 'empty';
}
    //endforeach;
/*    while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
        echo '<a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a><br>';
    endwhile;*/
//wp_reset_postdata(); // IMPORTANT - reset the $post object so the rest of the page works correctly

    foreach ($post_objects as $post): // variable must be called $post (IMPORTANT)
        setup_postdata($post);
        if (is_object_in_term($post->ID, 'tshowcase-taxonomy', Assistence)) {

            if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
                echo '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . "<br>" . get_the_post_thumbnail($postid, array(150, 150), array()) .  '</a><br>';
            } else {
                echo '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a><br>';
            }
            }
    endforeach;
    echo '<br>';
    /*    while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
            echo '<a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a><br>';
        endwhile;*/
    wp_reset_postdata();
```

The Loop for show all related posts works. But the upper code, to show only the headline shows also a headline, if there is no related post with this term.
Someone knows a solution for this problem?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to approach this given the code you have provided is to reverse the order of your code. Do the `foreach` before the title, and instead of outputting the post content using `echo`, append to a variable. Then check if the variable has anything to output and if so, output the title.

```
$post = $post_objects;
setup_postdata($post);

# create variable collect content
$content = '';

foreach ($post_objects as $post):
        setup_postdata($post);
        if (is_object_in_term($post->ID, 'tshowcase-taxonomy', Assistence)) {

                if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
                        # append content to $content variable
                        $content .= '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . "<br>" . get_the_post_thumbnail($postid, array(150, 150), array()) .  '</a><br>';
                } else {
                        # append content to $content variable
                        $content .= '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a><br>';
                }
                }
endforeach;

# check if $content variable has content
if( $content != '' ) {
    echo '<h4><i>' . Assistence . '</i></h4>';
    echo $content;
    echo '<br>';

}else{
    echo 'empty';
}

wp_reset_postdata();
```